# I get unable to load app 0 error while running django on uwsgi

Tags: python, django, celery, uwsgi

I run;

> uwsgi --http :8091 --module proj2.wsgi

But i get below errors;

```
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./proj2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app 
  File "./proj2/celery.py", line 5, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: No module named celery
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 13930, cores: 1)
```

When i check celery,

```
(proj2) [proj2@localhost proj2]$ which celery
~/Env/proj2/bin/celery
```

It is strange that if i run project with runserver, it works.

```
(proj2) [proj2@localhost proj2]$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 23, 2018 - 17:46:01
Django version 1.9.1, using settings 'pro.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

But not working with uwsgi...

Comment: rename proj2/celery.py as something else. It creates conflict with the actual celery app.

Comment: I changed name. Now error is : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./proj2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app 
ImportError: No module named celery

Comment: you have to change  "from .celery import app as celery_app" to  "from .<the_new_name_you_gave_for_the_file> import app as celery_app"

Comment: I changed it too. But still error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./proj2/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .orj_celery import app as celery_app
  File "./proj2/orj_celery.py", line 5, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: No module named celery

Answer (score 0):

At last i solved the problem.
I am serving two project on uwsgi and nginx. 
To manage processes using emperor for uwsgi. So probably proper configuration should be done to be managed wiğth emperor.

Solution :

proj2.ini file in /etc/uwsgi/sites for uwsgi should be like below.

```
[uwsgi]
py-autoreload = 2
project = proj2
username = proj2
base = /home/%(username)

chdir = %(base)/work/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = %k

uid = %(username)
socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(username):nginx
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=pro.settings
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%(project).log
```

wsgi.py under project directory should be like below :

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append("/home/proj2/Env/proj2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj2.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Emperor : Create uwsgi.service

```
Create a Systemd Unit File for uWSGI

    sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service

    > uwsgi.service

        [Unit]
        Description=uWSGI Emperor service

        [Service]
        ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown <USER>:nginx /run/uwsgi'
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
        Restart=always
        KillSignal=SIGQUIT
        Type=notify
        NotifyAccess=all

        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So, when you start uwsgi with  "sudo systemctl start uwsgi" , all django sites will be live with ini files from /etc/uwsgi/sites/. Then Nginx will serv them with sock files from /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock files.